# opendir error with first two images codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, readdir, opendir

i am reading from a directory which everything it looks fine. I am able to display all the data inside the folder but i have a problem, in the beginning of the list it shows 2 broken images which are not mine they have a strange path it looks like is generated it self, here is the strange path in the source file:

> (Resource id #33< ul >< li >< a href="#">< img src="img/test/.">< /
>   a>< / li>< li>< a href="#" >< img src="img/test/..">< /a> )

The code continue normally as it should reading the images inside the folder after these two lines.

And here is the code i am using:

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model{

public function getData(){

$dir = 'img/test';

echo opendir($dir);

if (is_dir($dir)) {

    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

     $display_models = '<ul>';

        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

    $display_models .= '<li><a href="#"><img src="'.$dir.'/'.$file.'"></a></li>';

        }

    $display_models .= '</ul>';

        closedir($dh);

    }

      return $display_models;
}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi add one if condition to check . and .. like this

```
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
        $display_models .= '<li><a href="#"><img src="'.$dir.'/'.$file.'"></a></li>';
     }

}
```

check this tutorial can also help you [scanning folder with php](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/scanning-folders-with-php/?search_index=1)

Answer (score 1):

You doing this in model!

You need to do this on controller. Copy paste this in Controller and call the function, and you will get the correct result.

> Models are PHP classes that are designed to work with information in
>   your database. For example, let's say you use CodeIgniter to manage a
>   blog. You might have a model class that contains functions to insert,
>   update, and retrieve your blog data.

Comment: That is the model which above is reading from database , for short purpose i am returning the results and call them via controller to display on view.

Comment: But, you can do it controller and display on view! Why you need to use one class what are designed to work with data of database for this.

Comment: You mean using model only for connecting to DB and all other commands do it at the controller? But does my way has a bad effect on the page?

Comment: I don't know if it can be bad effect. BUT, I am fan of MVC and clean code. Model classes are for DB Queries. With Controllers call models, manipulate with these data, calculate something or whatever and load on view. In this form it will be more clear, secure and better!

Comment: Ok buddy, i will keep that i mind but think when you have many connection and calculations the controller may be a mess of code in the end.

Comment: But, If you have any calculation (math formula, or something that you give a parameter and return a result) you can use helpers. Just make helper, load on controller and use it. More read here: http://www.ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: Yes you are right, maybe i should change my way of coding and managing files into a project. THank you